# How to fix this syntax error near NUMBER?

Tags: mysql

I cannot spot my error what have I done incorrect?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'NUMBER(4,2), `description` text, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ' at line 9

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$this->db_pre}sales` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `slug` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    `location` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `bedrooms` int(3) NOT NULL,
    `bathrooms`int(3) NOT NULL,
    `property_type` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `floor_area` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `price` NUMBER(4,2),
    `description` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: There is no NUMBER data type in MySQL. Change it with FLOAT or DOUBLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NUMBER` type is *not* a part of the [MySQL spec.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

You should use **`DECIMAL`** (or `NUMERIC` — they are identical) instead.

> The `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, **for example with monetary data**. In MySQL, `NUMERIC` is implemented as `DECIMAL` … (my emphasis)

Answer (score 1):

The bathrooms row lacks a space after the column name.

Answer (score 0):

It should be **NUMERIC**, not NUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

a NUMBER fieldtype does not exist in mySQL. What do you want it to contain?